# Error Redirect Loop

Tags: asp.net

This web page has a redirect loop. 
The web page at `localhost:3613/SqaSuite/LessPermission.aspx` has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Here are some suggestions:

- Reload this web page later.
- Learn more about this problem:

  > Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
  >   redirects.

Despite of clearing cookies and having no recursive and/or many loop redirecting, I am having this error. 
help ?

Comment: Can you please share the code for the page mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could also be because `Button.PostBackUrl` is redirecting to the same page. That was my problem.

Answer (score 14):

Check if you have somewhere on your page (eg called "SamePage.aspx"), or somewhere global, this endless loop.

```
 Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx");
```

and change it to

```
 if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("SamePage.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{    
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default asp.net MVC enables OwinStartup and redirects to Login under Account controller. You can refer to Startup.Auth for the same. Doing as below will fix the issue.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```