# Window authentication result in redirect looping error

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, web-config

Tried to use Window Authentication mode for my ASP web form (***So I can retrieve the current user's name when hosted with IIS***), in an intratnet environment (only accessible via network login):
[image]

Result in error message below (The URL has 8000 character counts) :
[image]

Things I have attempted so far:

1) Increase maxQueryStringLength / max UrlLength in Web.config:

```
 httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="10999" targetFramework="4.5"
```

2) Make sure I do not have any redirect in my code:
[Error Redirect Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734266/redirect-loop-error)

3) Remove blackslash at the end of my URL:
[Remove Trailing Slash From the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287982/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-url)

4) Set UsePortNumber to true to preserve the port number:
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14375781/

5) Cleared browser cookie

Also there're some client-side javascript on my **default.aspx** that only check target browser (IE / Chrome / etc).  Is there some pieces I am missing that needs to resolve the URL too long issue?  Also, it is normal to have such long URL?

Comment: Here's an [infinite loop answer](http://port135.com/2014/11/24/infinite-redirect-loop-to-login-page-in-asp-net/) but it's very specific so might not be your problem.

Comment: @AmalDev thank you I will have a look and let you know soon

Comment: There's also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19601719/3585500) about IIS Express adding it's own authentication rules. Actually the whole page is filled with ideas but their aimed at MVC5.

Comment: @AmalDev your link on the first comment resolved the issue.  Disabling UseCookieAuthentication helps.  I wonder if those line are for cookie to store data only?  Also, please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem.
It is caused bny disabling the Anonymous Authentication on the site.
The solution that I found was to add the following to my appsettings in the web.config file:

```html
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had disabled UseCookieAuthentication and it resolved the problem.  I will also try disabling anonymous Auth and see and I have a feeling they're disabling the same occurrence of a specific authentication.